# Summarizing table and keeping other attributes (ArcMap)

Tags: arcgis-desktop

My original table in ArcMap is associated with polygons.  In some cases, a polygon can have two records but with different values for each record.

I can summarize the table based on unique value of each polygon as well as get the max value from the polygon - but I would also like to bring along the associated attributes with the max record in the summary.  Is there a way to do this in ArcMap or any other database/spreadsheet program.

Example

```
UniquePoly   Yield   Crop     Number of Acres
1             100    Wheat    125
1             75     Canola   60
```

My summary table would be:

```
UniquePoly    MaxAcres    CountofUniquePoly
1             125         2
```

But I also like to carry across the yield and crop in the summary table

```
UniquePoly    MaxAcres    Count    Yield    Crop
1             125         2        100      Wheat
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Are you using the Summarize Statistics tool to do this or are you working from the attribute table?  Either way please provide more precise details of what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done but your data *must sit in a geodatabase* so if your data is a shapefile then import that in first.

So my sample data is this:

[image: Data]

Run a summary stats tool on this data making sure the output ends up in the same geodatabase as your polygon data. This is really important!

[image: Summary stats tool]

Output of this is this:

[image: summary data]

So for each unique ID we know the maximum acres and the polygon count.

Now run the Make Query Table tool as shown below:

[image: Make Query Table tool]

I've highlighted the bits you need to set, this results in a table as shown below, what you wanted:

[image: Results]

**IMPORTANT: This is an in memory table, it does not exist anywhere, so you need to export it to make it permanent, deleting any fields you don't want.**